# Issue setting values in 2d Array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to set values of a 2d array at the specific index.

Each iteration is setting all contained arrays at the j index to the variable(number).

```
inputTensor dimensions 140x7 - 140 arrays of 7 
inputMinArray dimensions 1x7 - 1 array of 7 
inputMaxArray dimensions 1x7 - 1 array of 7 

  var transformedInputTensor = new Array(inputTensor.length).fill(new Array(inputTensor[0].length))
  for(let i = 0; i< inputTensor.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j< inputTensor[0].length; j++ ){
      number = scale(inputTensor[i][j], inputMinArray[j],inputMaxArray[j], outMin, outMax);
      transformedInputTensor[i][j] = number;
    }
  }
```

The function scale() only returns a single value.

Everything works as expected, except transformedInputTensor[i][j] = number;.

Have I missed something very simple or any suggestions? - Thank You

Comment: what's the problem exactly, does `scale` mutate `transformedInputTensor`?

Comment: "Everything works as expected, except transformedInputTensor[i][j] = number;" - You have to give us more details. In what way doesn't it work? Does `transformedInputTensor[i][j]` keep its original value? What happens if you temporarily comment out the `number = scale(...)`, and instead use something like `number = 5; transformedInputTensor[i][j] = number;`? What kind of a variable is `number`, after being returned as the result of `scale(...)`? What happens if you use `console.log(typeof number)`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the `scale` actually does, but you have an obvious error in initializing the `transformedInputTensor` array with the same inner arrays.

Use this instead and I hope, it would fix the problem:

```
var transformedInputTensor = [];
for(var i = 0, _i = inputTensor.length; i < _i; i++)
    transformedInputTensor[i][j] = [];
```